# RAILS: Custom function in where block

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

**shirt.rb**

```
[ id, size, color ]
```

As the input I get value `params[:size]` which equals for example 170. Data in `shirts` table `size` column stores in format - `"160-180"` (so it is a string)

How can I preform query like:

```
Shirt.where("parse_first_number(size) > ? AND parse_second_number(size) < ?", params[:size], params[:size])
```

Comment: That is bad design. Use separate columns.

Comment: @ndn this is what i got from previous developer

Comment: This doesn't mean you shouldn't fix it. If there isn't that much data in the table, the migration will be easy. If there is - you don't want to run the sql monstrosity you are going to write anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'd highly recommend you improve the database schema by having two values: `min_size` and `max_size`. You would then be able to do a much simpler query:

```
Shirt.where("min_size <= ? AND max_size >= ?", params[:size], params[:size])
```

The problem as you've proposed it is *possible*, but much more complicated.

Comment: @ndn this is what i got from previous developer, it is not my idea to store values like that

Comment: It would not be at all difficult to add new columns, and migrate the existing data. If you have lots of other code currently relying on the `size` attribute, which is not easy to migrate also (although I bet it probably is simple...), then you could temporarily leave the data duplicated.

Comment: First add the two new columns (db migration), then run: `Shirt.all.each {|s| s.update_attributes(min_size: s.size.split('-').first, max_size: s.size.split('-').last }`

Comment: @TomLord Using models in migrations creates some pretty obnoxious inter-dependencies. It's usually best to do migrations as pure SQL so that they run in the future even if that model no longer exists.

Comment: You could probably even just add a new method to the `Shirt` model: `def size; "#{min_size}-#{max_size}"; end` and 95% of the old code would still work fine.

Comment: @tadman I was not suggesting the above code be run **in the migration**. I agree that it should be a separate (one-off) rake task, or similar.

Comment: @TomLord If it's too difficult to express as SQL, yeah, a Rake task isn't a bad plan. I'm just warning against casually including model code in migrations. It always seems like a good idea at the time, then as your project matures and changes you can no longer run migrations from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

That's basically an issue with your stored data column type. If you store a string, the database cannot convert it to a number and compare it. One way would be to go with another database that support ranges but the more convenient way is to use either two columns (size_from, size_to) or store a named variant of your size and keep a valued constant in your code like

```
class Shirt
  SIZES = [ { large: (160..180), ... ].freeze
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me reiterate that this is bad design and you should use separate columns.

---

With that said, there is no database agnostic solution. Here is one for postgres. Note that this is ugly and slow:

```
size_in_bounds_condition = <<-SQL
  CAST(split_part(coalesce(size, '0-0'), '-', 1) AS integer) < ?
  AND
  CAST(split_part(coalesce(size, '0-0'), '-', 2) AS integer) > ?
SQL

Shirt.where(size_in_bounds_condition, params[:size], params[:size])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also ugly and slow(this is the essence of technical debt). But it might work for now if the Shirts table is small.

```
shirt_size = 170
shirts = [
  {id:1, size:"160-180", color:"red"},
  {id:2, size:"180-200", color:"red"},
  {id:3, size:"160-180", color:"blue"}
]

shirts.select do |s|
  min, max = s[:size].split("-").map(&:to_i)
  max > shirt_size && min < shirt_size
end

=> [{:id=>1, :size=>"160-180", :color=>"red"}, {:id=>3, :size=>"160-180", :color=>"blue"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails accepts a `Range` as value in a `#where` [hash condition](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions):

```
sizes = "160-180" # this comes from your DB I presume
min, max = sizes.split('-').collect(&:to_i)
Shirt.where(size: min..max)
```

---

If you want to check if the parameter provided is within range, it's just as simple:

```
def valid_size?
  sizes = "160-180" # again from your shirt in DB
  min, max = sizes.split('-').collect(&:to_i) # when you get tired of this line, it means it's time to refactor it
  # collapse the following into one line
  params[:size] &&                      # check for presence
    params[:size].between?(min, max) && # check if in range
    params[:size]                       # I guess you want to return the size if valid, rather than only a boolean
end

# Alternative checks, that don't need the presence check:
# - (min..max).member?(params[:size])
# - (min..max).include?(params[:size])
# I choose what I find more explicit and readable
```

---

Finally, I agree you should migrate the DB to have min and max size stored as two separate integers. So as usual, write a test for your function, then code the simplest solution to get the tests green. At that point, by all means, go ahead and refactor your DB :)

```
# migration
def up
  add_column :shirts, :min_size, :integer
  add_column :shirts, :max_size, :integer
  Shirt.find_each do |shirt|
    min, max = shirt.size.split('-').collect(&:to_i) # for the last time :)
    shirt.min_size = min
    shirt.max_size = max
    shirt.save!
  end
  remove_column :shirts, :size
end

def down
  add_column :shirts, :size, :string
  Shirt.find_each do |shirt|
    size = "#{shirt.min_size}-#{shirt.max_size}"
    shirt.size = size
    shirt.save!
  end
  remove_column :shirts, :min_size, :integer
  remove_column :shirts, :max_size, :integer
end
```